# Alphabetical sorting of custom post type - one letter per page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, sort, custom-post-type-archives

Basically what I am looking for is a way to sort custom post type in alphabetical order and separate each letter, so you have one letter per page. See illustration. Hopefully there is a plugin or another genious way to do this.

Link to illustration -> http://postimg.org/image/5yyhidf7n/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Showing your research and your efforts in code is a prerequisite. Due to the lack of that, your question currently is just a task and much too broad.

Comment: @kaiser I have a non-hierarchical CPT called fleet. I want to make the Archive to work as the image, where the posts sorts by letter. I haven't done anything on the actual sorting code, because I don't know if i should use something like MixItUp.js or use Wordpress for what it's worth. It can for UX purposes make it as a jQuery-portfolio-sorting-thing, but I am still not sure how to proceed...

Comment: Please not as a comment, but as an [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Building the navigation is pretty straight forward. You have a few possibilities afterwards, I'd suggest you build one page template and use a `GET`-parameter to sort it out.

### using a GET variable

Your Links in the navigation would be like: `http://www.example.com/yourpage?letter=a`

In the page template you make a simple query in the `wpdb`.

```
global $wpdb;
$yourposts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title LIKE %s
            AND post_type = 'yourposttype'
        ",
            $_GET['letter'] . '%' 
        )
);
```

You can just loop through the Array that is returned here.

### using a custom post type

You could also create a Custom post type `alphabet` or something like that. Create each Post in this CPT with the Letters of the alphabet ('a', 'b', ...)

This results in URLs like `http://www.example.com/alphabet/a`, and it is also really easy to build the alphabetical navigation with it.

In your `single-alphabet.php` you use the code above, but replace the `$_GET['letter']` with `get_the_title()`.
Of course, you can also achieve this using metadata, but the solution using a custom post type is quite elegant, as you get your URL structure delivered nicely without any effort.

### using a taxonomy

last, this is another way to go, but not really practical as you always have to assign your the taxonomy according to the title (post 'banana' has to get the taxonomy 'b').

Depending on what you try to achieve, I'd go with the version of the custom post type.

Comment: I have a non-hierarchical CPT called `fleet`. I want to make the Archive to work as the image, where the posts sorts by letter. I haven't done anything on the actual sorting code, because I don't know if i should use something like **MixItUp.js** or use Wordpress for what it's worth.
It can for UX purposes make it as a jQuery-portfolio-sorting-thing, but I am still not sure how to proceed...

Comment: +1 but don't forget escaping `GET/POST/REQUEST` stuff :)

Comment: @kaiser I was under the impression that `prepare` handles that for me?

Comment: It does a [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Better be on the safe side.