# WordPress alphabetical A-Z custom post type post result display

Tags: categories, permalinks, pagination, custom-post-type-archives

How to display WordPress custom post type result alphabetical letters or pagination? for a example i have a post type called "homeless". under homeless there are 50 states (categories). there are 259 listing under Arkansas. i want to show a alphabetical letters a-z in the Arkansas category. for a example if someone click on letter "B" it will show all listing under "Arkansas" begin with letter"B". can anyone have a suggestion or php code for this?. Please see the image . thank you and kind regards.
[image]

Comment: 1. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131333/alphabetical-sorting-of-custom-post-type-one-letter-per-page, 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671943/create-alphabetical-pagination-in-wordpress

Comment: Max Yudin Thank you for the good information  really appreciated it.:)

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you don't want to hard-code the alphabet links (i.e., if no posts start with a letter, then that letter is not shown in pagination at all).

```
// Always show pagination
// First, grab all posts.
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'homeless',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
// Next, grab the first letter of each title.
$firstLetters = array();
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $startingLetter = substr($title, 0, 1);
    $dupeFirstLetters[] = $startingLetter;
    // Remove duplicates
    $firstLetters = array_unique($dupeFirstLetters);
    // Alphabetize
    sort($firstLetters);
}
foreach($firstLetters as $letter) {
    // Output the letter pagination, only for letters that have posts
    echo "<a href=\"?letter=$letter\">$letter</a>";
}
// If there is a request for a specific "letter" in the query string
if(!empty($_GET['letter'])) {
    $letter = $_GET['letter'];
}
// Else, default to showing the first found letter
// i.e. A if there are any post titles starting with A
else {
    $letter = $firstLetters[0];
}
// Finally, run a custom query to display the posts - see Max's link #1 above for specifics
```

You can then run the query to pull just the posts starting with that letter, and display them however you want.

Comment: WebElaine thank you for the quick reply . this is a best way to start my project. thank you very much for the help.. :)